# Network monitoring in Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, web, web-applications

I want to create web app which can monitor network components status in my network. I think it must be like one page with icons of all network components which connected by lines. And every icons show component status.

I prefer Rails, but open for other tech.

Has any ideas to make it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with web apps, is you need to load the page to get the information about  your network. I guess it could be useful make a script which retrieves the information along the time (I usually use perl to do that) and a simple web interface to display the information given.

The web interface would be only used to display the information given by the script (service)

But think also there're a lot of open source projects whose do you're looking for...